# Any way to add Lion full-screen feature for TaskPaper by AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, fullscreen

I am using TaskPaper and, unlike most Mountain Lion apps, it appears that there is no way to make it go full screen. Would it be possible to use an AppleScript to make it go full screen in the same way other apps can? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Nope that's not something AppleScript can do.